# Filter out entries in child array

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq

How can I filter items in a json sub array?

For instance, with this:

```
{
  "country": "Australia",
  "cities": [
    "Melbourne",
    "Sydney",
    "Brisbane",
    "Perth"
  ]
}
```

I would need to filter out "Brisbane" and "Perth" to obtain.

```
{
  "country": "Australia",
  "cities": [
    "Melbourne",
    "Sydney"
  ]
}
```

I've tried different combinations of `select(something|test("Brisbane|Perth")|not)` without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use subtraction:

```
jq '.cities -= ["Perth", "Brisbane"]'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "country": "Australia",
  "cities": [
    "Melbourne",
    "Sydney"
  ]
}
```

Comment: much simpler than my answer!

Comment: Even simpler: `.cities -= ["Perth", "Brisbane"]`

Comment: Can't get simpler than `.cities -= ["Perth", "Brisbane"]`. Thanks

Comment: @peak: I like it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the update assignment operator `|=` in combination with `map`

```
jq '.cities|=map(if . == "Brisbane" or . == "Perth" then empty else . end)'
```

Comment: I've accepted Thor's answer for its simplicity but yours is more flexible to allow substring matching. eg: `'.cities |= map(if test("Per|Bris") then empty else . end)'`